# ffmpeg - store desired output to python variable

Tags: python, ffmpeg, process

If i run: `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy` i get:

```
ffmpeg version 2023-01-30-git-2d202985b7-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57. 44.100 / 57. 44.100
  libavcodec     59. 59.100 / 59. 59.100
  libavformat    59. 36.100 / 59. 36.100
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 56.100 /  8. 56.100
  libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
[dshow @ 00000236357d0480] "HP True Vision HD Camera" (video)
[dshow @ 00000236357d0480]   Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_04f2&pid_b6ab&mi_00#6&763f234&2&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 00000236357d0480] "Microphone Array (Intel® Smart Sound Technology for Digital Microphones)" (audio)
[dshow @ 00000236357d0480]   Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{E8824DE9-F848-47F1-BB2A-EB24E11050FC}"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

From this output i want to store: "HP True Vision HD Camera" (first video output) in a python variable.

Is this possible?

I am trying

```py
import subprocess
ffmpeg_command = ["ffmpeg", "-list_devices", "true","-f", "dshow", "-i", "dummy"]
pipe = subprocess.run(ffmpeg_command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=10**8)
output = pipe.stdout
lines = output.splitlines()
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("[dshow @"):
        if "(video)" in line:
            camera_info = line.split("\"")[1]
            print(camera_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use regular expression to parse the output, e.g.:

```py
import re

output = r"""ffmpeg version 2023-01-30-git-2d202985b7-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57. 44.100 / 57. 44.100
  libavcodec     59. 59.100 / 59. 59.100
  libavformat    59. 36.100 / 59. 36.100
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 56.100 /  8. 56.100
  libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
[dshow @ 00000236357d0480] "HP True Vision HD Camera" (video)
[dshow @ 00000236357d0480]   Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_04f2&pid_b6ab&mi_00#6&763f234&2&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 00000236357d0480] "Microphone Array (Intel® Smart Sound Technology for Digital Microphones)" (audio)
[dshow @ 00000236357d0480]   Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{E8824DE9-F848-47F1-BB2A-EB24E11050FC}"
dummy: Immediate exit requested"""


first_video = re.search(r'"([^"]+)" \(video\)', output)
if first_video:
    print(first_video.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
HP True Vision HD Camera
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip install pygrabber`

```py
from pygrabber.dshow_graph import FilterGraph

def get_available_cameras() :

    devices = FilterGraph().get_input_devices()

    available_cameras = {}

    for device_index, device_name in enumerate(devices):
        available_cameras[device_index] = device_name

    return available_cameras

camera_name = "video="+get_available_cameras()[0]
print(camera_name)
```

Prints: `video=HP True Vision HD Camera`

Comment: Is this an answer that solves the problem?

Comment: @Rob Yes i think so. (I can accept the answer tomorrow).